# C# application on Apple IOS

Tags: c#, .net, ios

I have got C# .Net based applications. Is there any way I can run these applications for Apple IOS. I don’t have resources to develop all applications from scratch.

Many Thanks,
Ni

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First of all, you can not just run your existing .NET programs unmodified on the iOS platform.

The .NET runtime does not work on iOS, nor will it (in relation to current app guidelines regarding runtime compilation). Mono has the same fate and will not run on the iOS platform.

Your only option is to get the code compiled to native iOS executables, and this will involve 3rd party tools.

One of those is the [MonoTouch](http://ios.xamarin.com/) product. It is not free.

Note that this is not a technical limitation. The .NET runtime *could* run on the iOS platform if Microsoft, or Mono made it for that platform, but Apple does not allow such runtimes (the ones that download/execute not-yet-100%-compiled code) on their platform at all.

This is the same problem that prevents Flash from executing on the platform. The way Flash has gone to solve this is to compile the Flash programs to native iOS executables.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the tools made by the [mono project](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page).

These will not support all of the MS namespaces (non of the windows specific ones, such as WMI) and your application code needs to be written to be cross platform (so using `Path.Combine` for directory paths instead of concatenations).

Try the [`MoMA`](http://mono-framework.com/MoMA) tools to see if your code is cross platform and get recommendations for fixing it if it is not.

Comment: Thanks Oded. Yes I had look at that option earlier. However, It is not free. Is there any other option available?

Comment: @Nirali - What do you mean it is not free? It is an open source project and is definitely free for Macs. Yes, you do need to purchase the environment (MonoTouch) for the iPhone/iPad but for a Mac, it's free.

Comment: If you need to create IOS apps, [MonoTouch](http://ios.xamarin.com/) is the answer. But still not free

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Xamarin](http://xamarin.com/ios) for IOS. Integrates nicely with Visual Studio otherwise you can use its own IDE.

You can also reference .net assemblies. Hope this helps.