# how to make iphone app in c#

Tags: c#, iphone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to make applications in C# for iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8126248/is-there-a-way-to-make-applications-in-c-sharp-for-iphone)

Are there ways to create iPhone apps in C#? If so, what are they? I want to know if there are other ways of making iPhone apps that don't involve me buying a mac.

Comment: Check out [MacInCloud](http://www.macincloud.com/) for your Mac, XCode, etc. needs.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7553557/c-sharp-application-on-apple-ios

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132859/how-to-build-iphone-apps-using-net-on-windows

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can make an iPhone app in C#, but you still need a Mac. The framework that allows you to do this is [Monotouch](http://xamarin.com/monotouch).